# i dont why it isnt printing the linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

this is my code for inserting a node at the head of the linked list. there is no error but my printllist function is not working I don't know why. I think I have done silly somewhere. help me out I am stuck here for 3 hours.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
  class Node
   {   public:
       int data;
       Node* next;
   };



void insert(int y,Node* head){
  
   Node *temp=new Node();
   temp->data=y;
   temp->next=head;
   head=temp;

}

void printllist(Node *head){

   if(head=NULL)
   {
      cout<<"list is empty"<<endl;
   }
   else
   {
      while(head!=NULL)
      {
         cout<<head->data<<" ";
         head=head->next;
      }
   }

}

int main(){

   Node *head;
   head=NULL;
   int x,y,z;

   cout<<"hey can you tell me how many number you want to insert"<<endl;
   cin>>x;
   for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
   {
      cout<<"enter the data that you want to insert"<<endl;
      cin>>y;
      insert(y,head);
      printllist(head);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The changes to `head` don’t reflect outside `insert` so it will stay `NULL`. You need a reference to a pointer

Comment: what does  `z` supposed to be?

Comment: i am a newbie can you elaborate little more please

Comment: @leech it nothing actually just forgot to remove

Comment: @vikash 1) SO is not tutorial site. To learn C++, consider learning from [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). 2) [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)

Comment: Also, since you are using C++ and C++ is a object-oriented language, you should put your fuctions in your class as methods.

Comment: Here, you should either return `head` from `insert`, or pass a `Node **head`. A parameter is a local variable of the function. Changing it does not change the caller variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linked list for stack, head->next keeps becoming null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28498069/linked-list-for-stack-head-next-keeps-becoming-null)

Comment: Admittedly it is C, but it is the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the head of the linked list by reference so that the changes which are made in the insert function actually remain preserved between the function calls. Also, keep in mind that all the new nodes are inserted at the beginning of the linked list. So, for example if you enter 1,2,3 as the three elements of the linked list, the print function will print 3 2 1.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
  class Node
   {   public:
       int data;
        Node* next;
   };
void insert(int y,Node** head){
  
Node* temp = new Node();
    temp->data = y; 
    temp->next = *head; 
    *head = temp;
}
void printllist(Node* head)
{
    if(head==NULL)
        cout<<"List is empty";
    while(head!=NULL)
    {
       cout<<head->data<<" ";
       head=head->next;
    }
}

int main(){

Node *head;
head=NULL;
int x,y,z;
  cout<<"hey can you tell me how many number you want to insert"<<endl;
  cin>>x;
  for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
  {   cout<<"enter the data that you want to insert"<<endl;
 cin>>y;
 insert(y,&head);
}
printllist(head);

return 0;
}
```